# PHP/Symfony - Why is Exception from controller rendered with Twig not caught in Production mode only?

Tags: php, symfony, exception, try-catch

I have 2 controller actions and one is rendered in a twig template of the other by render(controller(...)) function. If I throw an exception inside of the child action, it gets caught only in DEV mode and not in PRODuction, any ideas why and how to get around it?

**DefaultController.php**

```
/**
 * @Route("/test/child", name="test_child")
*/
public function childAction(Request $request)
{
    throw new \Exception($request->getRequestUri());

    return $this->render("child.html.twig");
}

/**
 * @Route("/test/parent", name="test_parent")
 */
public function parentAction(Request $request)
{
    try {
        return $this->render("parent.html.twig");
    } catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        die("got it!");
    }
}
```

child.html.twig

```
Child
```

parent.html.twig

```
Parent
<br>
{{ render(controller("WebBundle:Pages:child")) }}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use own exception handler (using event listener)?

Comment: `app.php` has disabled debug mode?

Comment: It probably happens because of debug mode, which means you should not treat exceptions on this way! Within sf of course, as said you need to look for the exception handler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a Symfony2 project, Twig catch exceptions by default in production mode.

You can configure it in order that all exceptions are thrown like in dev mode:

```
// app/config/config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    debug: true # default: %kernel.debug%
```

Or, configure an exception listener:

Service declaration:

```
// app/config/services.yml
app.exception_listener:
    class: Acme\CoreBundle\Listener\ExceptionListener
    arguments: [ "@templating" ]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

Class:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;

class ExceptionListener
{
    private $templateEngine;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templateEngine)
    {
        $this->templateEngine = $templateEngine;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $response = $this->templateEngine->render(
            'TwigBundle:Exception:error500.html.twig',
            array('status_text' => $event->getException()->getMessage())
        );
        $event->setResponse(new Response($response));
    }
}
```

Template for exception message trace/message displaying:

```
// app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error500.html.twig
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class='error'>
        <div class="message">
            <h2>Application Error</h2>
            <p>Oops! {{ status_text }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT**

To catch only specific exceptions, add the following at the beggining of your listener:

```
// Listen only on the expected exception
if (!$event->getException() instanceof RedirectException) {
    return;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would it be possible to listen to just one type of exception? For example: RedirectException, so I could get the value and make a redirect?

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying it out right now. I'm getting an error in the service configuration file though. Working on it now.

Comment: There is a type, it has to be "tags: - { ...}

Comment: Thanks for the report! Edited

Comment: The only possibility is that the first argument passed to the exception is not a string. Can you verify that the argument passed when you throw the exception is a string ?

Comment: Ok, I though I solved the problem, so I deleted the comment, but it holds. And it occurs even if I don't use the exception anywhere in the code!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108542/discussion-between-chalasr-and-mike).

Comment: This is my code: class RedirectException extends \Exception { } ... if I get rid of the extends \Exception part, all start working

Comment: Ok, I actually run into another problem and that is, $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse(...)); is not working in production. Any idea why? :/

Comment: It's surely not coming from the setResponse itself. Can you remove all in the cache directory and look at your log?

Comment: Surely mandatory to handle twig exceptions while the debug is disabled. Good idea to try the combination!

Answer (score 1):

The `render` filter has an option that you can use to do that: `ignore_errors`.

```
{{ render(controller('WebBundle:Pages:child'), {'ignore_errors': false}) }}
```

By default it's set to `!$debug`, so in production is `true`. You can disable it like that. With this the exception is [re-throw](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/f29d46f29b91ea5c30699cf6bdb8e65545d1dd26/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Fragment/InlineFragmentRenderer.php#L106) even in production.

Comment: Tried this and works perfectly. However, I'm probably going to go with the other answer by @chalasr as it seems to give more flexibility to my code. :-) Thanks so much anyways!

Comment: you really want set `debug: true` on production?

Comment: @Federico The most flexible alternative is the EventListener (that I give in my answer). It allows to handle only some specific exceptions.